# Can These Plants Be Saved?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, diseases, mint

I believe the more dead one is sage. How should I help it? Also the plant with brown ends on the stems is mint. Should I cut off the brown bits? I don't care about harvesting or eating them I mostly just want to help them but I'm not sure how.

I would gladly appreciate any links to some good sites for learning how to care for them. There's so much info and I'm not sure where to start

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They all (including the succulent) look like they had too little light, and probably not enough (or not any!) fertilizer in the soil.  Basically, they starved to death in the dark :(

Comment: Hi, SkylineStrawberries and welcome! We are glad you decided to join us and I hope you won't be disappointed I removed your identification request, but we need the questions to be separated because otherwise people might be tempted to answer only partially with what they know and others to assume that you got everything while you are still waiting for the missing part. So please post a new question for ID other plants and I am sure you will receive wonderful answers from fellow plant growers.

Comment: I would not call any of them dead yet. They certainly need an intervention. Nice light, some fertilizer, good temperature, pruning of dead bits, and the proper amount of water.

Comment: Wayfaring is correct they can be saved, but before you do, do you know what you did wrong?  If not, cleaning them up and getting them ready to grow again will end in disappointment.

Answer (score 1):

From your few pictures, it looks like some combination of lack of light, infrequency of watering, too low of temperature, and/or not enough fertilizer. Cut off the brown and leafless parts unless they connect a leafy part to the pot. Put them in a south-facing window that doesn't get below freezing, if you have one. Get a fork and some used coffee grounds, put the coffee grounds on top of the dirt, and use the fork to loosen the top inch of soil. Give them each water, maybe half a cup each for now. Might want to put something underneath the pots so the water doesn't ruin a windowsill.

You might be doing some of these things already; it's really hard to tell given the overall neglect. But neither one is dead, and they'll spring back in a month or two with some TLC.